Error en funcion store, no entra a dicha función
No se donde me equivoco ahora, comparándolo con otros controllers, y con otras funciones del mismo blade, no logro que entre en la función del storePartida, algo hay mal, claro esta, pero no lo veo.....
Esto es el codigo del formulario:
    <form action="{{ route('storePartida') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input type="number" placeholder="Código" name="codigo">
        @error('codigo')
            {{ $message }}
        @enderror
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre">
        @error('nombre')
        {{ $message }}
        @enderror
        <input type="date" placeholder="Fecha" name="fecha">
        <select name="juego_id" id="">
            <option value="Juego" disabled selected>Juego</option>
            @foreach ($juegos as $juego)
                <option value=" {{ $juego->id }} ">{{ $juego->nombre }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Jugadores" name="jugadores_partida">
        @error('jugadores_partida')
            {{ $message }}
        @enderror
        <input type="text" placeholder="Comentarios" name="comentario">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        <p><button class="btn btn-primary"> <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Cancelar</a></button></p>
    </form>

Y esta la parte del controlador:
public function storePartida(Request $request){
    $request->validate ([
        'codigo'=>'required|unique:juegos',
        'nombre'=>'required',
        'jugadores_partida'=>'required'
    ],[
        'codigo.required' => __('El código de la partida no puede estar vacio'),
        'codigo.unique' => __('El código esta en uso, debe ser úinico'),
        'nombre.required' => __('El nombre de la partida es obligatorio'),
        'jugadores_partida.required' => __('Los jugadores son obligatorios')
    ]);
    die('entra aqui');
    $partida = new Partida;
    $partida -> codigo = $request -> codigo;
    $partida -> nombre = $request -> nombre;
    $partida -> fecha = $request -> fecha;
    $partida -> juego = $request -> juego;
    die(json_encode($partida));
    $partida -> jugadores_partida = $request -> jugadores_partida;
    $partida -> comentario = $request -> comentario;
    die(json_encode($partida));
    $partida -> save();
    return view("home");
}

A la cual entra a la parte de las validaciones que las hace bien, pero en el "die('entra aqui') ni llega.
Alguno ve lo que no logro ver, llevo con esto una mañanica larga y parte de la tarde de ayer...

Como sabes que las validaciones las hace bien y no lanza un exception?

Porque las probé, y el primer "die", no salta, lo que me queda es ver que da o que variable es la que pasa de las validaciones....

Prueba a quitar el resto de los die, solo dejar 1, y cambialo por dd(), este es dump and die para laravel, y debería funcionar mejor. Verifica igual que el validate no te este mostrando una exception

Los die fueron "check points" a ver si pasaba por ahí...ya se porque decías lo de las "excepciones", tras corregir un desliz, la tabla no era correcta....ya funciona..... procedo a ver si puedo ponerte que la solución la indicaste tu @Excorpion
